# Getting the result with the Promise keyword

Tags: javascript, isodate

I am using Dialogflow to pass the dateofbirth and convert it into ISO format using a particular function written in helperfile in webhook end.

I am trying to call a function in a helper file that converts the date of birth to ISO format and return the date in Javascript.

But it gives the result as Promise {2020-01-20:00:00:00} instead of the actual value.

The code in the helper file is given below:

```
const formatdob = async (df,globalParameter,dob) => {   //birthDate should be in mm/dd/yyyy format
    try {
                     
        console.log("globalParameter",globalParameter);
        let dob = df._request.queryResult.queryText //  Capturing the input from user  
        globalParameter["dob"]=dob;                                          
        if(dob.length!=0){    //function to convert into a ISO format                                        
            const d = new Date(dob);    
            return Date(
                Date.UTC(
                d.getFullYear(),
                d.getMonth(),
                d.getDate(),
                d.getHours(),
                d.getMinutes(),
                d.getSeconds()
                )
            
            ).toISOString();


 }
        }
      
    catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
        throw err;
    }


};

module.exports = formatdob;
```

I call the function using

```
dob= formatdob(df, globalParameter,dob);
console.log("dob",dob);
```

When I print the value,I get :

```
dob Promise { '2020-01-01T00:00:00.000Z' }
```

I want only the value to be printed.I am a beginner to Javascript . I also tried using await keyword while calling the function but it returned the same result...Could you please help me out with this?

Comment: `Promise` is not a keyword, it's a global property.

Comment: I see no asynchronous function here, so you might just be able to fix this by simply removing the `async` keyword.

Comment: @MinusFour - just to be precise [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) is an Object.

Comment: @RandyCasburn it's a global property which holds a constructor function (which is an object but then again just about anything is or can be an object)

Comment: @MinusFour - Oh for goodness sake - here is _the_ definition: [ECMAScript® 2022 Language Specification](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/control-abstraction-objects.html#sec-promise-objects) - but, hey - you can be right if that makes you feel better.

Comment: If I remove the async keyword,I get TypeError: Date(...).toISOString is not a function

Comment: @MinusFour If I remove the async keyword,I get TypeError: Date(...).toISOString is not a function

Comment: @lakshmi It's irrelevant to the `async` keyword. You need to do `new Date(...).toIsoString()`

Comment: @MinusFour Thanks...removing the async keyword at last helped me...Can you please provide me any specific links to get the basic understanding of these concepts-async ,promise ?I read some of those but its somewhat confusing.